# How can I sync text together with a narrated audio file and make the text scroll together with the audio (like karaoke)?

Tags: flutter, dart

In my app, I would like to play an audio file and show text so that the user can read along with the audio. I would like this text to scroll automatically so the user doesn't lose their position.
To get the auto-scrolling to work, I thought I could animate a list view that displays the correct text based on timestamps, however, that would make adding new audio laborious as I would have to manually go through each audio and add the text with timestamps so I am hoping there is a better way to do this.

How can I sync an audio file together with text without having to create timestamps?
Is it possible to use a speech recognition library in Flutter to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Karaoke usually uses Lyric(LRC) file format to display lyrics. The format is similar to how subtitle(SRT) files are - where timestamp is defined with the text to be displayed. There are tools to help you generate Lyric files like [Aegisub](https://github.com/Aegisub/Aegisub/).

There's yet to be a way to sync audio and text without timestamps. If you're leaning into that approach, the closest that I've seen so far is auto-generated captions - something similar to how it's applied on YouTube.

**Parsing Lyrics**

This is not a complete sample, but you can use [lyrics_parser](https://pub.dev/packages/lyrics_parser) plugin to parse the timestamp(milliseconds) and text. You may consider storing the timestamp-lyrics in a Map or List<Model> depending on your preference.

**Highlight Text**

To highlight the lyrics, you can consider using [highlightable](https://pub.dev/packages/highlightable) plugin.

**Lyrics**

Populate a ListView row dynamically
depending on the size the View can handle (width / estimated String length). Say a character has an estimated 5.0 in width. A ListView row with a width 200 can handle an estimated 36 characters per row if we bump the estimated character width to 5.5 - to factor in spacing and padding. Add a new ListView row if the size exceeds the estimated row width.

To fetch the view's width, you can use LayoutBuilder. This widget fetches its parent widget's dimensions.

```dart
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
  debugPrint('Max width: ${constraints.maxWidth}');
})
```

**Auto scroll**

To manage auto scroll feature, you can keep track the first timestamp displayed on the row and use [ScrollController.animateTo()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/animateTo.html) to navigate to the specific row.

**Time sync**

For syncing time, you can consider using [Timer.periodic](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html), and highlight the text using `highlightable` plugin when the timestamp on the ticker matches with the lyrics'

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    HighlightText(
      lyricsText,
      detectWords: true, // set to true to highlight text
    ),
    ...
  ],
)
```

Comment: So let's say I have the timestamps, how would I go about creating an autoscrolling feature, to sync the audio with the text as in the question? If you edit your answer with a complete sample I'll reward you bounty. See [this](https://imgur.com/a/rXNS3TX) is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: It's not a complete sample, but I can provide a guide on how it can be achieved.

Comment: thanks! I will probably use a map where the key is the word and the value is the timestamp. I will wait for other/complete answers. If you have time consider updating your answer for likely to get the bounty